# Linux bash script, recursion for adding numbers

Tags: linux, bash, recursion

I want to figure it out how recursion works in bash scripting.

I want to insert number as a parameter:

```
sh script.sh 4
```

And result would be (1+2+3+4)= 10

This is what I wrote and in my head works just fine, but can't make it work.

```
n=$1
j=1
result=0

recursion(){ 
    result=`expr $result + $j` 
    j=`expr $j + 1`

    if [ "$n" -gt 0 ]; then
        recursion      #is this how you do recursion?
        n=`expr $n - 1
    else
        echo $result 
    fi
}

recursion
```

I think I imagined right but probably I am wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682524/recursive-function-in-bash

This may help

Comment: `expr` is generally deprecated -- there's no reason to use it in modern POSIX-derivative shells. `$(( ))` lets you do math in any POSIX shell, and `(( ))` lets you do the same without results being expanded in bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use global variables:

```
#!/bin/bash

add_recursively () {
    local n=$1
    local sum=${2:-0}
    if (( n == 0 )); then
        echo $sum
        return
    fi
    $FUNCNAME $((n - 1)) $((sum + n))
}

# input validation
if ! [[ $1 =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
    echo "I need a non-negative integer, not $1"
    exit 1
fi

echo $(add_recursively $1)
```

Notes:

- `local` declares the named variables to be local to this function ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-local))
- `sum=${2:-0}` defines the "sum" variable as the 2nd parameter, or 0 if the 2nd parameter is empty or unset ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion))
- `$FUNCNAME` name of the currently running function ([ref](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables)). This is the recursive call, passing "n-1" and "sum+n" as the parameters.

Comment: +1. That said, might suggest more quotes just to better demonstrate good practices. (Granted, they're less necessary for numeric values than in other cases, but if someone passes in `'1 23'` as a number, better to detect it that way and fail with an appropriate error).

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I just can't make this code work. I get this error in terminal - script.sh 11: script.sh n: not found, script.sh 15: script.sh: 4: not found
I'm new to scripts so I don't know what this mean.

Comment: You are invoking the script like `sh script.sh 5`, that's a problem: this is a **bash** script, so you need to run it with a **bash** interpreter: `bash script.sh 5`. Or, give it execute permissions and run it like a program: `chmod u+x script.sh; ./script.sh 5`

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to run it. Can you pleas explain a little bit what does code do? 
I want to know what this do - local sum=${2:-0}
and what this do - $FUNCNAME $((n - 1)) $((sum + n))

Answer (score 2):

This can be implemented as a shell function:

```
rec() { [ "$1" -gt 0 ] && echo $(( $1 + $( rec $(($1-1)) ) )) || echo 0 ; }
```

Here are sample results showing `rec` being defined at the command line and then run for several cases:

```
$ rec() { [ "$1" -gt 0 ] && echo $(( $1 + $( rec $(($1-1)) ) )) || echo 0 ; }
$ rec 4
10
$ rec 5
15
$ rec 6
21
```

**How it works:**  The function `rec` takes a single integer argument.  It first checks if that argument is greater than zero.  This is done using `test`: `[ "$1" -gt 0 ]`.  If it is greater than zero, it adds the argument to the result of `rec $(($1-1))`.  If the argument is zero, it just returns (echoes) zero.

**Implemented using if/then/else:** Some may find it more clear if the `&&`/`||` logic is replaced with an `if` statement:

```
rec() {
    if [ "$1" -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo $(( $1 + $( rec $(($1-1)) ) ))
    else
        echo 0
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this recursive function:

```
recuradd() {
    n=$1
    [[ $n -eq 0 ]] && return
    (( res += n-- ))
    recuradd $n
}
```

Then call using:

```
res=0; recuradd 4; echo $res
10

res=0; recuradd 5; echo $res
15
```

Comment: This is a loop hiding as tail recursion. It doesn't use local variables, and actually depends on variable `rec` being reused.  Not good, not bad, but risky.