# Directory depth in recursive script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

hi i'd like to get some help with my linux bash homeworks.
i have to make a script that gets a directory and returns the depth of the deepest subdirectory (+1 for each directory).
I must do it recursively.
I must use 'list_dirs.sh' that takes the virable dir and echo its subdirs.

thats what i got so far:

```
dir=$1
sub=`source list_dirs.sh`

((depth++)) 

for i in $sub
do
  if [ -n "$sub" ] ; then
      ./depthScript $dir/$i
  fi
done

if ((depth > max)) ; then
   max=$depth
   echo $max
fi
```

after testing with a dir that supose to return 3 I got insted:

```
1
1
1
1
```

it seems like my depth counter forget previous values and I get output for 
   each directory.. need some help!

Comment: instead of global variables, you can pass it as an argument to your script.

Comment: but why depth is concidered as local and not global in my script? how does it work? any way i think im not allowed to change the input of the script which is dir only

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bash functions](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html) to create recursive function calls.

Your function would ideally echo `0` in the base case where it is called on a directory with no subdirectories, and echo `1+$(getDepth $subdir)` in the case where some subdirectory `$subdir` exists. See [this question on recursive functions in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682524/recursive-function-in-bash) for a framework.

Answer (score 0):

When you run a script normally (i.e. it's in your `PATH` and you just enter its name, or you enter an explicit path to it like ./depthScript), it runs as a subprocess of the current shell. This is important because each process has its own variables. Variables also come in two kinds: shell variables (which are only available in that one process) and environment variables (the values of which get exported to subprocesses but not back up from them). And depending on where you want a variable's value to be available, there are three different ways to define them:

```
# By default, variables are shell variable that's only defined in this process:
shellvar=something

# `export` puts a variable into the environment, so it'll be be exported to subprocesses.
# You can export a variable either while setting it, or as a separate operation:
export envvar=something
export anotherenvvar
anotherenvvar=something

# You can also prefix a command with a variable assignment. This makes an
# environment variable in the command process's environment, but not the current
# shell process's environment:
prefixvar=something ./depthScript $dir/$i
```

Given the above assignments:

- `shellvar` is defined in the current shell process, but not in any other process (including the subprocess created to run depthScript).
- `envvar` and `anotherenvvar` will be inherited by the subprocess (and its subprocesses, and all subprocesses for later commands), but any changes made to it in those subprocesses have no effect at all in the current process.
- `prefixvar` is available *only* in the subprocess created to run depthScript (and its subprocesses), but not in the current shell process or any other of its subprocesses.

Short summary: it's a mess because of the process structure, and as a result it's best to just avoid even trying to pass values around between scripts (or different invocations of the same script) in variables. Use environment variables for settings and such that you want to be generally available (but don't need to be changed much). Use shell variables for things local to a particular invocation of a script.

So, how should you pass the depth values around? Well, the standardish way is for each script (or command) to print its output to "standard output", and then whatever's using the script can capture its output to either a file (`command >outfile`) or a variable (`var=$(command)`). I'd recommend the latter in this case:

```
depth=$(./depthScript "$dir/$i")
if ((depth > max)) ; then
    max=$depth
fi
```

Some other recommendations:

- Think your control and data flow through. The current script loops through all subdirectories, then at the end runs a single check for the deepest subdir. But you need to check each subdirectory individually to see if it's deeper than the current max, and at the end report the deepest of them.
- Double-quote your variable references (as I did with `"$dir/$i"` above). Unquoted variable references are subject to word splitting and wildcard expansion, which is the source of much grief. It looks like you'll need to leave `$sub` unquoted because you *need* it to be split into words, but this will make the script unable to cope with directory names with spaces. See [BashFAQ #20: "How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020)
- The `if [ -n "$sub" ] ; then` test is irrelevant. If `$sub` is empty, the loop will never run.
- In a shell script, relative paths (like `./depthScript`) are relative to whatever the working directory of the parent process, *not* to the location of the script. If someone runs your script from another directory, `./depthScript` will not work. Use `"$BASH_SOURCE"` instead. See [BashFAQ #28: "How do I determine the location of my script? I want to read some config files from the same place."](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)
- When trying to troubleshoot a script, it can help to put `set -x` before the troublesome section. This makes the shell print each command as it runs, so you can see what's going on.
- Run your scripts through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net) -- it'll point out a lot of common mistakes.